# Error while starting rails server everytime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am new to ubuntu system. Whenever I am trying to start my rails server I have to write **source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm**. Is their any way i can start my rails server without writing this command. Ubuntu version I am using is 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you try next: `echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

- Your Terminal -> Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command ->
  Check the "Run command as a login shell" Done